# Android CharSequence filter() trouble

Tags: android, filter

I am having trouble with simple filter for EditText.
Trying to handle deleting symbols (prevent deleting symbols in some cases).
Here on example I want to prevent deleting of any characters.
In case of pressing backspace (source="") I am returning "" (i.e. nothing)
But I still can delete all the characters from EditText.

```
@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                           Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

    if (source.equals("")) {
        return "";

    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

During the debugging I somehow getting into the `return ""`
but then I am getting into `return null`.

[image]
Why?

Comment: it could be just an issue with the debugger. Did you try printing out the return value?

Comment: yes. Somehow I am getting bothg

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
MyEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {                 
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {                 
                     if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){                        
                           return true; 
                         }                  
                return false;       
                    }
            });
```

Comment: i want to handle deletion inside of the filter in order to prevent deleting some symbols

Comment: I did not actually understand what you want

Comment: want to prevent deleting some character in edittext. I.e. there must be 3 numbers which I can not delete, but all others can (whrn the number has more digits)

Comment: so you can implement my answer with checking the content of the textView